# How do I set a Calendar with TimeZone?

Tags: java, java.util.calendar

I have a timestamp that I am trying to put into a `Date` object, however when I use Calendar, I am running into a strange problem.  I seem to be able to unable to create a Date object with the values I want:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Date today = new Date();
    int hour = 4, min=0, sec=0, ms=64;

    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    cal.clear();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));
    cal.setTime(today);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,sec);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,ms);

    System.out.println("Time is: "+cal.getTime());
}
```

This produces:

```
Time is: Mon Jan 13 23:00:00 EST 2014
```

which is ***not*** the result I am looking for.

However, if I comment out the 'setTimeZone' method call, I get the following result:

```
Time is: Tue Jan 14 04:00:00 EST 2014
```

This is the result that I am looking for but I am concerned that if I am running on a machine that is not running in the same time zone, I will not get consistent behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that Java does not know of the timezone "EDT" (Eastern Daylight Time).  As a result, Calendar seems to be setting the timezone to GMT.

The timezone needed here is "America/New_York" or "EST5EDT".  When either of these values are used, the correct result is produced.

The list of valid Time Zones can be obtained by calling `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`

It is unfortunate that no warnings are produced when the requested Time Zone is not found.

Answer (score 2):

> This is the result that I am looking for but I am concerned that if I am running on a machine that is not running in the same time zone

it is the problem. The internal representation should be ok, but it prints on local timezone: **representation differs from real content**.

use `SimpleDateFormat` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and set TimeZone to see the date on the Zone desired.

Comment: Nope. SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy") produces the same result.

Comment: Did you set the TimeZone of SimpleDateFormat? It uses JVM TimeZOne!

Answer (score 0):

If you can do away with `java.util.Date`, you can use [joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) time API to conveniently set these values as desired:

For your query, you can set your already created Calendar instance as a constructor parameter to `DateTime`.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(cal);
System.out.println(dt.toDateTimeISO());
```

**Output:**

```
2014-01-14T04:00:00.064-05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.getTime()` returns a `java.util.Date` object. `Date` objects do not know anything about timezones. The `Date` object that `Calendar.getTime()` returns does not know to what timezone the `Calendar` that it came from is set.

When you print a `Date` object (for example, by implicitly calling `toString()` object, as you are doing) it is formatted in the default time zone of the machine you are running it on.

If you want to print a `Date` in a specific timezone, use a `SimpleDateFormat`, and set the desired timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat` object. For example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));

// Will display the date that the calendar is set to in the EDT timezone
System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Date objects represent the number of milliseconds seconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT due to the fact that the other methods are deprecated.  The two ways to "view" a Date object directly are "getTime()" and "toString()" (using "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy").  Therefore, you are formatting the GMT value to your local timezone.

When working with dates, it is best to think of them as GMT values, and then as a "formatting" exercise when viewing the date.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here is that same kind of code but using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

Avoid the java.util.Date & .Calendar classes.

Never use three-letter codes for time zones. They are neither standardized nor unique. Instead use [proper time zone names](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html). In this case, use "America/New_York" or "America/Montreal".

```java
// Use time zone names, such as from this slightly outdated list: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );

// Input.
int hour = 4, min = 0, sec = 0, ms = 64;

// Start with now, then adjust the time of day.
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime dateTime = now.withHourOfDay( hour ).withMinuteOfHour( min ).withSecondOfMinute( sec ).withMillisOfSecond( ms );

// If needed, translate to a java.util.Date for use with other classes.
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "date: " + date );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-20T21:04:51.237-05:00
dateTime: 2014-01-20T04:00:00.064-05:00
date: Mon Jan 20 01:00:00 PST 2014
```